# Retrieve an id from CustomView instantiate in an other class

Tags: java, android, textview

Basically I have a list of Textview for each Title in a ExpandableListView.

I'd like to put an id from database in an attribute of TextView for retrieve it later. I created a CustomView "ChampText" with a CustomAttribute idveh which is the id.

```
public class ChampText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{

public String idveh;

public ChampText(Context context){
    super(context);
}

public ChampText(Context context, AttributeSet attribute) {
    super(context, attribute);
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attribute, R.styleable.ChampText);
    idveh = ta.getString(R.styleable.ChampText_idveh);
    ta.recycle();
}

public String getIdveh() {
    return idveh;
}

public void setIdveh(String idveh) {
    this.idveh = idveh;
}
}
```

And the attrs.xml :

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="ChampText">
    <attr name="idveh" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I create my list of "ChampText" in the method getData() :

```
public HashMap<String, List<ChampText>> getData(List<VehiculeModel> list) {

    List<String> expVehicule = new ArrayList<String>();

    HashMap<String, List<ChampText>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<ChampText>>();


        for (VehiculeModel vehicule : list) {
            List<ChampText> expTextViewVehicule = new ArrayList<ChampText>();
            ChampText mesPleins = new ChampText(context);
            ChampText supprimer = new ChampText(context);
            String nomVehicule = "";

            String vehid = String.valueOf(vehicule.getId());
            nomVehicule = vehicule.getVehiculeNom() + "\n" + vehicule.getVehiculeType();

            mesPleins.setText("Mes Pleins");
            mesPleins.setId(vehicule.getId());
            mesPleins.setIdveh(vehid);

            expTextViewVehicule.add(mesPleins);

            supprimer.setText("Supprimer");
            supprimer.setId(vehicule.getId());
            supprimer.setIdveh(vehid);

            expTextViewVehicule.add(supprimer);

            expandableListDetail.put(nomVehicule, expTextViewVehicule);

        }

    return expandableListDetail;
}
```

At this moment, my id is the good id (1 for first vehicule, 2 for second, etc) and I try to assign it to the attribute idveh for each item I create for each vehicule.

On my MainPage, my Views ChampText are well created, and I set them like this :

```
<com.bonobocorp.joker.litrocent.ChampText
    android:id="@+id/expandedListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:onClick="onClickTextView"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

The value of Text is well informed and I can put the id on the Text, it's working well, but if I put the id on my attribute idveh of my CustomView, when I recover my view on my MainPage and try to print the value of my id on my method "onClickTextView" like this :

```
public void onClickTextView (View expandedListItem) {

    ChampText listItem = (ChampText) expandedListItem;
    String idveh = ((ChampText) expandedListItem).getIdveh();
    System.out.println(idveh);
}
```

The value of idveh is always "null".

How can I retrieve my id on all items of my list of ChampText (or TextView) to trigger an action based on the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my issue.

I got a class who's generate my view (my child view especially).

and I got this method in :

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ChampText expandedListText = (ChampText) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    ChampText expandedListTextView = (ChampText) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
    expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText.getText());
    expandedListTextView.setIdveh(expandedListText.getIdveh());
    return convertView;
}
```

I added the line : `expandedListTextView.setIdveh(expandedListText.getIdveh());` on the end.

and obvisously, it works..

Well thanks Guys to take time anyway !!!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attribute, R.styleable.ChampText);
```

the only difference is that you'll use getTheme method from the context

Comment: It doesn't work. If i put on my constructor who take Context and Attribute set, it says 'Wring 1st argument, required int,  found AttributeSet' and if i complete my first constructor who just take a context with this:    `public ChampText(Context context){
        super(context);
        TypedArray ta = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.ChampText);
        idveh = ta.getString(R.styleable.ChampText_idveh);
        ta.recycle();
    }` The id i get is always null :/